# Any trick to having multiple iOS development certificates?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, provisioning

I've been doing iOS development for my own company for a couple years. I now need to work on a project for another company. They've made me an admin under their account and I'm staring at the "development certificates" page. Back in the bad old days when we first started doing iOS development there were complaints that you couldn't have multiple developer certificates without screwing things up.

I don't mind jumping through some hoops to get set up for the new company but I don't want to risk messing up my primary configuration for my own development work. Is it really as simple as just going through the steps again to request and download another development certificate and the two can live side by side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it really is as simple as that. Make sure you name everything properly and things will work like a charm. 
I currently have three different certificates linked to my developer account and never got into trouble. 
Edit: Ooops, recounting, its a lot more as I do have some customer-of-customer certs linked as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance. It looks like Apple punched up XCode to handle this situation. It may be the only thing that works in this very convoluted system of certificates and provisioning profiles! :-)